# If $A = \int_Xf\ d\mu$, then $\sqrt{1+A^2} \ \le \ \int_x\sqrt{x+f^2}\ d\mu \ \le \ 1+A $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measue space with $\mu(X)=1$ and $f:X\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ is measureble. Let
$$A = \int_Xf\ d\mu$$ 
Show that 
$$ \sqrt{1+A^2} \ \le \  \int_X\sqrt{x+f^2}\ d\mu \ \le \ 1+A $$

The first equality seems obvious but I don't know how to officially prove and I'm completely stuck with the second equality. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are $a$ and $x$ small ? Are you thinking of $X$ as some subset of $R$ ?

Comment: @Umberto P. Thanks for sharing the link to the other question. But I'm still stuck with the first equality.

Comment: OP in the linked question explained how to prove the first inequality.